# Extracting 4 bits from N to N+4 in unsigned long

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Consider the following integer:

`uint32_t p = 0xdeadbeef;`

I want to get:

- 0..3 bits so I did:
  `p & ((1 << 4) - 1);` and that went good.

however, for 4..7 what I tried did not go as expected:

`(p >> 16) & 0xFFFF0000`

Why would it not extract the bits I want? Am I not moving `p` 16 positions to the right and then taking out 4 bits?

Would really appreciate an answer with explanation, thanks!

Comment: `(p >> 16) & 0xFFFF0000` will extract bits 32 to 47 (these will be zero for a 32-bit integer). What were you expecting?

Comment: didn't know that, I expected from 4 to 7

Comment: A hex digit corresponds to 4 bits. Try (p >> 4) & 0x0f

Comment: Works, mind posting an answer?

Comment: you mean bit or byte? bit is 0 or 1. byte is 8 bits

Comment: I belive I never mentioned bytes in my question, did you mean something else?

Comment: moving with 16 positions, means move 16 bits and not 4 bits. you have to move 4 position to get bits from 4 to 7.

Comment: It would be better is you stated "I want to get X and I am getting Y"

Comment: @MOHAMED so, if I want to get, say from 8 to 12 I would do `(p >> 8) & 0xF0`?

Comment: If you mean from 8 to 11. then `(p >> 8) & 0x0F`

Comment: If you want form N to N+3. then `(p >> N) & 0x0F`. It's mentioned in my answer with details

Comment: Ah, thanks, that pretty much explains it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get bits from 4..7

```
(p>>4) & 0xf
```

If you want to get bits from `N` to `(N+4-1)`

```
(p>>N) & 0xf
```

And `N` should be <32 (if your system is 32 bits system). otherwise you will get undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

No, you're actually removing bits 0 to 15 from p, so it will hold 0xdead and afterwards you perform the bitwise and so this will yield 0.

If you want to extract the upper 16 bits you will first have to the & operation and shift afterwards:

```
p = (p & 0xffff0000) >> 16;
```

To extracts the bits 4 to 7 you will want to do:

```
p = p & 0xf0;
```

or if you want them shifted down

```
p = (p & 0xf0) >> 4;
```

Btw. Could it be that mean the term nibble 4 to 7 instead of bit 4..7? Nibbles are 4 bits and represented by one hex digit, this would correlate with what you are trying to in the code

Comment: `i'm removing bits from 0 to 15` (that's the `p >> 16` correct?) so then I have from 16 to 32 (aka highest bits) and then performing bitwise would take out 8 more bits, leaving behind another 8 bits right?

Comment: Also, why exactly ANDing with `0xF0`?

Comment: @user 0xf0 is bits 4-7. So p & 0xf0 will set all the other bits except 4-7 to 0. Then you shift all your bits 4 places to the right. So now the bits 0-3 contains the bits that was 4-7, i.e. you get the value of bits 4-7. This can be done with `(p >> 4) & 0x0f` as well. If you do `(p >> 16)` , you're shifting all bits 16 places to the right - so bits 4-7 would vanish - you're only left with what was the 16 uppermost bits.